# How to get pulseaudio volume in C?

Tags: c, linux, pulseaudio, x-dwm

I am writing my own status bar program for suckless dwm and the last thing left on the list is getting volume percentage from default pulseaudio sink. In bash, I have solved this with this pipe:

`pactl list sinks | awk '$1=="Volume:" {print $5}'`

Is there a good way to do it in C?

Comment: This code exactly works on my system. (debian+xfce)

https://gist.github.com/jasonwhite/1df6ee4b5039358701d2

Comment: consider before compile install: `libpulse-dev`library for a debian base: `sudo apt install libpulse-dev`

Comment: Change volume with default `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin` in my desktop, the code can correctly show the correct volume.